# C+ How to variables / Arduino

Tags: arduino

How can i make it simple? I have predefined numbers under L0 to L9. When program gets number for example 32 i need to write it under LX as L3 and under LY as L2. Anyone has an idea how to do this ? I need to make it form 0 to 64 
`if(number == 64){LX=L6;LY=L4;} 
  if(number == 63){LX=L6;LY=L3;}
  if(number == 62){LX=L6;LY=L2;}`

Answer (score 1):

You don't give any details on what the type of `LX`, `LY` and `L0`..`L9` is, but from what I can see, you want to use each digit of `number` to look up your corresponding "predefined number" and then put the tens digit in `LX` and the ones digit in `LY`.

A straight-forward way is to do the lookup explicitly with a switch
in a function

```
   /* Convert x (in [0..9]) to corresponding "predefined number" */
    L_type get_L_num(int x)
    {
        switch(x) {
            case 0: return L0;
            ...
            case 9: return L9;
            default: if needed, some error handling...
    }
```

(where `L_type` is whatever type your predefined number variables are) and use that for each digit as in

```
{LX = get_L_num(number/10]; LY = get_L_num[number%10]}
```

Another alternative is to put L0..L9 in an array `Lnumbers` and then index that as

```
{LX = Lnumbers[number/10]; LY = Lnumbers[number%10]}
```

and, if you need to, add range checks for `number`.

Please note that the use of just `/10` to find the tens and `%10` to find the ones assumes that `number` is in [0..99], (which it should be since you asked about [0..64])